# Dynamic CollectionViewCell size using AutoLayout not rendering properly

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview

I currently have my `UICollectionView` set up in the IB like so:
[image]

The bottom constraint has it's constant changed to the height of the keyboard when the keyboard appears:

```
 func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let keyboardHeight = getKeyboardHeight(notification)
    keyboardHeightConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight + 20

    print(cardCollectionView.frame)

    self.cardCollectionView.configureCollectionView()
    self.cardCollectionView.reloadInputViews()
}
```

Where `configureCollectionView()` is:

```
    func configureCollectionView() {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    // Create the layout
    let space = 10.0 as CGFloat
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    let width = (self.frame.size.width) - 4 * space
    let height = (self.frame.size.height)

    let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 2 * space, 0, 2 * space)

    // Set top and bottom margins if scrolling horizontally, left and right margins if scrolling vertically
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = space
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

    // Set horizontal scrolling
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal

    // Set edge insets
    flowLayout.sectionInset = edgeInsets
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, height)
    self.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)

    // Always allow it to scroll
    self.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true

}
```

Now the problem arises when the keyboard appears: 
[image]

When the keyboard first appears the `CollectionView` gets resized and then `configureCollectionView()` is called. As a result the `CollectionViewCell` should also get resized but instead it looks like it's being clipped by the bounds of the resized `CollectionView`.

This can be seen as in the 2nd image in the GIF (after the keyboard appears) there are no rounded corners on the bottom and the 4 buttons are there.

It seems like when I click another `TextView` the `CollectionViewCell` goes back to it's correct size, although it still has an `alpha = 1` even though nowhere in my code did I set the `alpha` to one.

To get my final desired result, I had to dismiss the keyboard.

What is wrong with my implementation, what can I do different to achieve my desired result when the keyboard is shown instead of having to go through all of the above?

Comment: Did you try like this `collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()` with keyboard show or dismiss.

Comment: Here is my suggestions: 1. Configure the collection view in the `viewDidLoad' func not every time the keyboard shows and update the item size  in `keyboardWillShow`, 2. Call `reloadData` but 'reloadInputViews' after you update the constraint and item size. See if this will help.

Comment: I do configure the collection view in `viewDidLoad`. Although I'm a bit confused as to how to update the itemsize in `keyboardWillShow`. Isn't the only way to update the `itemSize` to create a new `UIFlowLayout` which is why I am calling the `configureCollectionView` in the first place.